# Export dataframe to multiple excel workbooks in R with conditional formatting intact

Tags: r, excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have a dataset that I'd like to export to multiple Excel workbooks with conditional formatting. I can't post the actual data, but a sample is below. Essentially, I've got a dataset showing whether or an individual qualifies for a survey, what department and team within the department they are in:

| Survey Status | Department | Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Budget Off | Acts |
| 0 | Budget Off | Acts |
| 1 | Sales | Local |
| 1 | Public Rel | Social |

I want to do the following:

1. Conditionally format the data so that rows with a survey status of 1 are in bold, black text and rows with a survey status of 0 are in non-bold, red text for easier reading.
2. Maintain this formatting when exporting to Excel.
3. Creating an individual workbook for each Department/Team grouping.

I can format the data how I'd like within R, and I can create an individual workbook for each Department/Team grouping without a problem.

The issue is that the formatting gets lost. I've tried a few different packages, including xlsx, openxlsx, formattable, and condformat, but can't seem to bridge the gap so that the formatting is applied within the Excel files.

I was previously able to do this is SAS with no problems. We're transitioning to R, which is why I'm recreating these documents. However, I'm wondering if R is the best choice for this procedure. Perhaps Python would be better?

Thanks in advance for all your help. The SO community is my lifeline in learning to code, and has been an invaluable resource.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx/man/conditionalFormatting.html

Comment: Hi Adam. Thanks for the suggestion, but yes, I've tried that without luck, unfortunately. The output produces a corrupt file that doesn't maintain the formatting. There's a very good chance that my inexperience is to blame, so I will go over this documentation closely to see what I've got wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Finally discovered the problem with the help of YouTuber CradleToGraveR. User error! It was in the formula for the "rule" within conditionalFormatting()

I had been using the formatting examples in the documentation for openxlsx (e.g., rule = "$colname=1", but applying it to a string (e.g., rule = "$colname=YES"), which is why Excel didn't recognize it.

When conditionally formatting strings, use single quotes around the rule with double quotes around the value (e.g., rule = '$colname="YES"').

CradleToGraveR shows how to format for text values in this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACdCQuQJxhU